# R dplyr:: rename and select using string variable

Tags: r, string, dplyr, rename

I am trying to select a subset of variables in my dataframe, and rename the variables in the new dataframe. I have a large number of variables that I would need to rename. I am using

```
dplyr::select
dplyr::select_
```

Since I have number of variables to rename, I am thinking if I should use a string variable to rename, but not sure if it could be possible? Using a string helps me to manage the newname oldname mapping. Here is an example

```
dplyr::select
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13) 
set.seed(123)
data <- sample_n(flights, 3)

select(data,yr=year,mon=month,deptime=dep_time)
```

The question how could I pass the arguments for this in a string, that is the newvariable=oldvariable arguments and then use

```
dplyr::select_

col_vector <- c("year", "month", "dep_time")
select_(data, .dots = col_vector)
```

The string I have in mind are:

```
rename_vector <- c("yr=year","mon=month","deptime=dep_time")
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Why not change column names with `colnames(data) <- col_vector`?

Comment: Is the real question how to auto generate `col_vector` without manually constructing it? Then, you have to provide some logic of how you want to rename these columns.

Comment: @Gopala in my case I dont have to change all column names, only a subset of it. Also by having the "new name = old name" not only makes it readable, but also ensures there is a direct 1-1 match. Think of 50 variable names.

Comment: You can selectively rename columns using `names(mtcars)[c(1, 2, 3)] <- c('z', 'y', 'z')` or using names as `names(mtcars)[names(mtcars) %in% c('x', 'y', 'z')] <- c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')`.

Comment: In case you just want to rename some variable but not all of them, this answer could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44143688/3871924

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using a vector, you can pass a list to `.dots` in `dplyr::select_`, where the names are the new column names and the old names are characters.

```
> rename_list <- list(sepal_length = "Sepal.Length", sepal_width = "Sepal.Width")
> iris %>% tbl_df %>% select_(.dots = rename_list)

Source: local data frame [150 x 2]

   sepal_length sepal_width
          (dbl)       (dbl)
1           5.1         3.5
2           4.9         3.0
3           4.7         3.2
4           4.6         3.1
5           5.0         3.6
6           5.4         3.9
7           4.6         3.4
8           5.0         3.4
9           4.4         2.9
10          4.9         3.1
..          ...         ...
```

Answer (score 15):

**dplyr**

Another option using `dplyr` in conjunction with `setNames` to pass the vector with the new column names:

```
iris %>%
  select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>% 
  setNames(c("sepal_length","sepal_width"))
```

**Base package**

```
setNames(iris[, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")], 
         c("sepal_length", "sepal_width"))
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setnames(iris, old = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), new = c("sepal_length","sepal_width"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `rename_with` you can do something like:

```
old = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
new = c("sepal_length", "sepal_width")
iris %>% 
  dplyr::select(all_of(old)) %>%
  dplyr::rename_with(~ new, all_of(old))
```